# careers says github project is hidden

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

For some reason http://careers.stackoverflow.com says:

Hidden We couldn't find any commits you've made to this project.

For https://github.com/Karaage-Cluster/karaage/commits/master

This is just a bit weird, because I have made a lot of commits to this project, and github is correctly seeing them as my commits.

Possibly problem is the commits were made with my old email address. My research seems to suggest this shouldn't matter though, as long as github can associate it to my user.

I previously asked about this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274539/careers-github-project-is-hidden) however was [told](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275771/where-do-i-get-support-for-stack-overflow-careers) that this is the correct place to ask.

Comment: It works fine for my other projects. So I don't think that is it.

Comment: @Dean Ward I am getting the same error for the repo https://github.com/omergul123/LLSimpleCamera/  which I have my commit listed https://api.github.com/repos/omergul123/LLSimpleCamera/commits

Comment: @SandeepAggarwal you should really post as a separate question, but cursory inspection indicates that there are no commits for the user you logged into GitHub with when connecting the account to your CV: https://api.github.com/repos/omergul123/LLSimpleCamera/commits?author=SandeepAggarwal. Do you have multiple GitHub accounts?

Comment: @DeanWard NO, I don't have multiple Github accounts. I made a pull request to this repo  github.com/omergul123/LLSimpleCamera and using this api https://api.github.com/repos/omergul123/LLSimpleCamera/commits?author=SandeepAggarwal , one can't get the commiter who made a pull request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a look through the GitHub projects you have associated with your account and the only ones I can find that mention karaage are https://github.com/brianmay/karaage and https://github.com/karaage/karaage.

If I go to GitHub's API to find commits by you on [Karaage-Cluster/karaage](https://api.github.com/repos/karaage-cluster/karaage/commits?author=brianmay) I see commits and that's what we use to determine whether to show the project in your CV or not.

Is it possible you mistakenly used the karaage/karaage project rather than the Karaage-Cluster one?

Comment: Oh crap. Looks like you are right, I linked the wrong project by mistake. Stackoverflow working as designed. I have fixed this now. Thanks for you help.